# How do I make all photos display properly?

Tags: html, css

I just started learning html and css and am working on a theme for my blog. Most gifs and photos show up with no problem, but some of my photo posts only display this: [torn photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQROV.png) How do I make all photos display properly? Below is the html:

```
{block:Photo}
    <div class="post">
        <img src="PhotoURL-500}">
      {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
        <ul class="like-reblog">
          <li>{LikeButton}</li>
          <li>{ReblogButton}</li>
          <li>{block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}#notes">{NoteCount}</a>{/block:NoteCount}</li>
          <li>{block:Date}<a href="{Permalink}">{Month}&#x2606;{DayofMonth}{DayOfMonthSuffix} {Year}</a>{/block:Date}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    {block:PostNotes}{PostNotes}{/block:PostNotes}
{/block:Photo}
```

Here is the CSS:

```
 .post {
    background: #fff;
    margin: 40px auto;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
```

I'm still learning so I may have missed something.

Comment: What is your question

Comment: Oops, sorry. I just added my question in the original post, but I'm asking how do I make all photos display properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That icon usually appears when the image isn't found (wrong name, file extension, filepath, file not existing at all or similar error). Apart from that, it seems like you are missing a curly bracket here:

```
<img src="PhotoURL-500}">
```

That should probably be:

```
<img src="{PhotoURL-500}">
```

Answer (score 0):

this usually happens to linking errors.
Try and upload the image to a website or moving the file to another location.
And using that new location for the img